# How to redirect multiple pages to another page in Apache?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I wish to have something like this:

```
rewritecond "mydomain/path/to/somepage.html"
rewritecond "mydomain/path/to/somepage2.html"
rewritecond "mydomain/path/to/somepage3.html"
```

then
redirect to "mydomain/path/to/destinationpage.html"

Comment: It'd help if you show what the actual problem is, what you tried, where you failed etc.